# C# WinForm label font looks pixelized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used Application.EnableVisualStyles() even now the label font on my form looks pixelized (ie., Like DOS character) How can I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Better to add a screenshot

Comment: Looks pretty good to be...

Comment: Yea, But this is Calibri Font, The font is not supposed to be like this.

Comment: Windows Forms uses GDI+. If you want DirectText, use WPF.

Comment: O_o so rebuild my 1 year old project ?

Comment: I didn't say you have to rebuild it, though you may or may not have other reasons to do so. I'm just saying Windows Forms uses GDI+, so you're probably out of luck. You might want to look at your Cleartype settings in control panel though.